# combine multiple exe files into one in the taskbar by batch file

Tags: windows

I have a batch file which runs 10 exe files (small exe files of size 8-10 KB). I want to combine them into one and hide the label (in the taskbar) with the help of batch file only.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: When I run the batch file, the exe files occupy a lot of space on the taskbar. I want to combine them (group similar taskbar buttons) using the batch file.

Comment: Are you familiar with [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)? It allows you to combine taskbar buttons with specific Application IDs (or hide labels).